# Bash insert a comma (,) after every third field of a variable or array?

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, awk

I have a variable with the following contents: `"a b c d e f g h i j k l"`, how would you go about adding a comma sign (,) after each third member so it looks like this: `"a b c, d e f, g h i, j k l"`.

Initially all my variable data is stored in an array so if anyone knows how to directly manipulate the array, it would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

awk

```
$ echo "a b c d e f g h i j k l" | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if(i%3==0){$i=$i","}  }1'
a b c, d e f, g h i, j k l
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bash:

```
arr=(a b c d e f g h i j k l)
ind=("${!arr[@]}")    # get the indices of the array (handles sparse arrays)
ind=(${ind[@]:0:${#ind[@]} - 1})    # strip off the last one
# add commas to every third one (but the last)
for i in "${ind[@]}"; do if (( i%3 == 2 )); then arr[i]+=","; fi; done
echo "${arr[@]}"  # print the array
declare -p arr    # dump the array
```

Results in:

```
a b c, d e f, g h i, j k l
declare -a arr='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c," [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f," [6]="g" [7]="h" [8]="i," [9]="j" [10]="k" [11]="l")'
```

If you don't mind the last element also having a comma, you can use the indices more directly (omit the lines that set `$ind`):

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do if (( i%3 == 2 )); then arr[i]+=","; fi; done
```

If you're not worried about the array being sparse:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}-1; i++)); do if (( i%3 == 2 )); then arr[i]+=","; fi
```

which is basically the same as **ghostdog74's** answer except that Bash arrays are zero-based and awk fields are one-based.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
$ a=(a b c d e f g h i j k l)
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"|paste -sd'  ,'
a b c,d e f,g h i,j k l
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 echo "a b c d e f g h i j k l" | sed 's/\(\w \w \w\) /\1, /g'
```